# Error while building octomap_server

Tags: octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FUERTE on ubuntu 12.04 and using rosbuild

I am encountering this error while compiling the octomap pkg

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package):
By not providing "Findnodelet.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "nodelet", but
CMake did not find one.

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "nodelet" with any
of the following names:

  nodeletConfig.cmake
  nodelet-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "nodelet" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"nodelet_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"nodelet" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
```

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/octomap_mapping/trunk/octomap_server/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118611/error-while-building-octomap_server/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2014-01-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-01-16**:
thank you, installing the debian package solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where are you building octomap_server from (which source repository, which version)? And why not simply install the debian package "ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping"?

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2